# Switch "reveal" for "revealing" any rule?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I have this text:

1.0:  "Julia Ducournau becomes the second woman to win the top prize, after Jane Campion in 1993.
The surprise **reveal** came at the start of a chaotic ceremony." NY Times. What if I write it like:

1.1: "Julia Ducournau becomes the second woman to win the top prize, after Jane Campion in 1993.
The surprise **revealing** came at the start of a chaotic ceremony."

In the 1.0 version the word "reveal" at first glance looks like a verb. Can I just switch it for the 1.1 version without breaking any grammatical law?

Comment: Did you look up [the definition of **reveal** as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reveal)?  I would say switching it out for *revealing* is grammatically correct, but less fluent and idiomatic.

Comment: What's wrong with 'revelation'?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch lots of nouns without breaking grammar rules, but if you want to keep the intended meaning, "reveal" is the best choice.

The noun form of "reveal" refers to an **intentional** revealing of some previously hidden information. In a mystery novel, the "reveal" is the part towards the end of the book where the reader finds out who committed the crime. "Gender reveal parties" are a modern fad where the sex of an unborn baby is disclosed by the colour of the inside of a cake, or the colour of glitter that comes out of exploding targets.

The winner of a prize being announced is intentional, so "reveal" is better.

A "revealing" is a derived noun form of the verb "reveal", with no special meaning. It includes accidental revealings, such as showing your cards in poker, or letting a secret slip out.